# How can i display post according to distance filter

Tags: php, laravel, rest, lumen

I'm creating Post API in lumen framework that contains users detail and fetch their current latitude and longitude for each post.
How can I make API where the post is visible to a specific distance (like the post should be visible within 10km) to the users who are present in that area. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not to good in lumem but I know that it is micro version to laravel so it i have created the php script that works on **`the laravel OR PHP OR other PHP FRAMEWORKS`**

```
/**
    * @function     calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints
    * @author       Manojkiran <manojkiran10031998@gmail.com>
    * @param        string  $latitudeOne
    * @param        string  $longitudeOne
    * @param        string  $latitudeTwo
    * @param        string  $longitudeTwo
    * @param        string  $distanceUnit
    * @param        boolean $round
    * @param        string  $decimalPoints
    * @usage        calculates the distance between  latitude and longitude coordiates
    * @version      1.3
    **/
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | calculates the distance between  latitude and longitude coordiates by different distance units such as miles,kilometes etc
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    |
    |Usage:
    |Option 1: Returning the round value of the distance
    |echo calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints('11.657740','77.766270','11.074820','77.002160','ML',true);
    |
    |Option 2: Returning the Distance with specific decimal points
    |echo calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints('11.657740','77.766270','11.074820','77.002160','ML',false,2);
    |echo calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints('11.657740','77.766270','11.074820','77.002160','ML',false,7);
    |
    */

    function calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(float $latitudeOne, float $longitudeOne, float $latitudeTwo , float $longitudeTwo,string  $distanceUnit ='KM', bool $round = false , int $decimalPoints = 3)
    {

        $distanceUnit = strtolower($distanceUnit);
        $pointDifference = $longitudeOne - $longitudeTwo;
        $toSin = (sin(deg2rad($latitudeOne)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTwo))) + (cos(deg2rad($latitudeOne)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTwo)) * cos(deg2rad($pointDifference)));
        $toAcos = acos($toSin);
        $toRad2Deg = rad2deg($toAcos);

        $toMiles  =  $toRad2Deg * 60 * 1.1515;
        $toKilometers = $toMiles * 1.609344;
        $toNauticalMiles = $toMiles * 0.8684;
        $toMeters = $toKilometers * 1000;
        $toFeets = $toMiles * 5280;
        $toYards = $toFeets / 3;


              switch (strtoupper($distanceUnit)) 
              {
                  case 'ML'://miles
                         $toMiles  = ($round == true ? round($toMiles) : round($toMiles, $decimalPoints));
                         return $toMiles;
                      break;
                  case 'KM'://Kilometers
                        $toKilometers  = ($round == true ? round($toKilometers) : round($toKilometers, $decimalPoints));
                        return $toKilometers;
                      break;
                  case 'MT'://Meters
                        $toMeters  = ($round == true ? round($toMeters) : round($toMeters, $decimalPoints));
                        return $toMeters;
                      break;
                  case 'FT'://feets
                        $toFeets  = ($round == true ? round($toFeets) : round($toFeets, $decimalPoints));
                        return $toFeets;
                      break;
                  case 'YD'://yards
                        $toYards  = ($round == true ? round($toYards) : round($toYards, $decimalPoints));
                        return $toYards;
                      break;
                  case 'NM'://Nautical miles
                        $toNauticalMiles  = ($round == true ? round($toNauticalMiles) : round($toNauticalMiles, $decimalPoints));
                        return $toNauticalMiles;
                      break;
            }             
    }
```

> Explaination

Arguments

`$latitudeOne => which indicates the latitude of point one`

`$longitudeOne => which indicates the longitude of point one`

`$latitudeTwo => which indicates the latitude of point two`

`$longitudeTwo => which indicates the longitude of point two`

`$distanceUnit => sets that in which unit the distance needs to be calculated`

**`AVAILABLE UNITS[ML => MILE(S),KM => KILOMETER(S),MT => METER(S),FT => FEET(S),YD => YARD(S),NM => NAUTICAL MILE(S)]`**

Defaults to **KM**

`$round => Set to true if you want to round of the value`

```
$decimalPoints => Set the number of digits that need to be added for the float values
```

So In Your Situation You can pass the parameter as follows

```
echo calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints('11.657740','77.766270','11.074820','77.002160','KM',false,0);
```

Comment: thanks for your guidance buddy but still is it possible that suppose I created a Post and I want the post to be visible to all my users within that specific area. From what I can understand is that this code looks for distance between two specified points

Comment: yes its is possible you can get the current user lattitute and longitude based on the ip address  https://ipstack.com/  and you can pass those values to my function

Comment: what I meant to say is that I have all users latitude and longitude stored in my user's table and i have another table called post. When an individual creates a post it will capture the lat and lon while creating a post and send it to post table. I want my post's table api to look for 10km distance in users table and show them that post

Comment: can you share some data

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('mysql1')->create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unique(10);
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('location');
            $table->string('title');
         
            $table->string('description');
           
            $table->float('lat');
            $table->float('lon');           
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('mobile')->unique();
          
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->float('lat');
            $table->float('lon');  
            $table->integer('flag')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: so when user creates posts it will store creating users lat and long and look for users whose lat and long is within 10km or 15km distance

Comment: public function store(Request $request){         $this->validate($request,   $rules);  $post = new Post; $post->setConnection('mysql1');  $user= User::where('token', $request->token)->first();  if ($user) { $a = Auth::user()->id; $post =  Auth::user()->posts()->create([ 'user_id' => Auth::id(),  'post_id' => rand(),  'title' => $request->title, 'description' => $request->description, 'serve_quantity' => $request->serve_quantity,   'lat' => $request->lat,  'lon' => $request->lon,            ]);